# Find a sum $S = \sum\limits_{t \in E} \sum\limits_{x \in E} (t + x)(t + x^2)...(t+x^{2p})$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, complex-numbers, summation, generating-functions

I am solving a problem that has already a plan for the solution. As a subproblem I have to find the value of 
$$S = \sum\limits_{t \in E} \sum\limits_{x \in E} (t + x)(t + x^2)...(t+x^{2p})$$

where $E$ is a set of all $p$-th roots of unity and $p$ is a prime number.

I also know the right answer (but cannot get the solution yet): $$S = p (\binom{2p}{p} + 4p - 2)$$

**Small clarification: you don't have to read the wall of text below. This is just my attempt to get an answer and the real problem has been already told in the begging.**

So, what I have done:

The plan goes like this:

1. First fix $t$ and sum $x$
2. Split the sum into two sums for $x = 1$ and $x \neq 1$ ($S(t) = S_1(t) + S_2(t)$)
3. The last step is to sum $t$.

Lets find out $S_1(t) = \sum\limits_{t \in E} (t + 1)(t + 1^2)...(t+1^{2p})$.
Obviously, it is $S_1(t) = \sum\limits_{t \in E} (t + 1)^{2p}$

The first problem is to find out $S_2(t)$. I think, I can prove that:
$$S_2(t) = \sum\limits_{w \in E \setminus \{1\} } (t + w)(t + w^2)...(t+w^{2p}) = (p - 1)(t + w_1)(t + w_1^2)...(t+w_1^{2p})$$
where $w_1 = exp(\frac{2\pi i}{p})$

But I am not sure that is actually true. this is can be rewritten as:
$$(p - 1)((t + w_1)(t + w_1^2)...(t+w_1^p))^2$$
The next problem is to find the value of $$(t + w_1)(t + w_1^2)...(t+w_1^p)$$
It is easy to find the coefficient of $t^p$ (clearly, it is $1$), $t^{p-1}$ (not so obvious, but it is $0$ for sure) and $t^0$ (easy to show that it is $1$). So, my guess is that the hole polynomial equals to $t^p+1$.

If I was correct (but I still want the proof for all this statements), then:
$$S = \sum\limits_{t \in E} [(t+1)^{2p} + (p - 1)(t^p+1)^2]$$
Let's split it again:
$$S' = \sum\limits_{t \in E} (p - 1)(t^p+1)^2 = 4 p (p - 1)$$
$$S'' = \sum\limits_{t \in E}(t+1)^{2p} = \sum\limits_{t \in E} \sum\limits_{i=0}^{2p} \binom{2p}{i} t^i = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{2p} \binom{2p}{i} \sum\limits_{t \in E} t^i$$
But I think (but have not proven that yet) that $\sum\limits_{t \in E} t^i = 0$ for every $i \neq p$. And then we can rewrite $S''$:
$$S'' = p \binom{2p}{p}$$

And the final result is then:
$$S = S' + S'' = 4 p (p - 1) + p \binom{2p}{p} = p(\binom{2p}{p} + 4p - 4)$$
And it is not correct, so I have somewhere a mistake =(

Well, I am sorry for such a long introduction. You can help me a lot if you find a mistake in my thoughts and/or help with missing proofs. Alternative solutions are welcome as well =)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the bigger problem that this is a subproblem of?

Comment: @RusMay The hole problem comes from the International Mathematical Olympiad that was held on 1995 (IMO 1995). And here it is: "Let $p$ be am odd prime number. Find the number of subsets $A$ of the set {1, 2, 3, ..., 2p}" such that $A$ has exactly $p$ elements, and the sum of all the elements in $A$ is divisible by $p$". Now, you can easily proof that the answer is $\frac{1}{p}(\binom{2p}{p}+2p-2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an evaluation of your sum with the usual machinations of changing order of the summands and factors. However, there is a combinatorial twist at the end.

Let $p$ be a prime and $\omega=e^{2\pi i/p}$. Then your sum is
$$S=\sum_{k=1}^p\sum_{\ell=1}^p\prod_{m=1}^{2p}(\omega^k+\omega^{\ell m}).$$
Factor out $\omega^k$ from each term in the product. This gives a combined factor of $\omega^{2pk}=1$. So,
\begin{eqnarray*}
  % \nonumber to remove numbering (before each equation)
    S &=& \sum_{k=1}^p\sum_{\ell=1}^p \omega^{2pk}\prod_{m=1}^{2p}(1+\omega^{\ell m-k}) \\
      &=& \sum_{k=1}^p\sum_{\ell=1}^p \prod_{m=1}^{2p}(1+\omega^{\ell m-k}) .
  \end{eqnarray*}
Now expand the product and use the property of exponentials $\omega^a\omega^b=\omega^{a+b}$. As notation for this expansion, let $\wp(n)$  denote the collection of all subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, and let $\sum M$ denote the sum of the elements of the set $M$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
% \nonumber to remove numbering (before each equation)
  S &=& \sum_{k=1}^p\sum_{\ell=1}^p\sum_{M\subseteq\wp(2p)}\prod_{m\in M}\omega^{\ell m-k} \\
    &=& \sum_{k=1}^p\sum_{\ell=1}^p\sum_{M\subseteq\wp(2p)}\omega^{\ell\sum M}\cdot\omega^{-k|M|}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Then  change the order of the summands and factor.

\begin{eqnarray*}
% \nonumber to remove numbering (before each equation)
  S &=& \sum_{M\subseteq\wp(2p)}\sum_{k=1}^p\sum_{\ell=1}^p\omega^{\ell\sum M}\cdot\omega^{-k|M|} \\
    &=& \sum_{M\subseteq\wp(2p)}\left(\sum_{k=1}^p\omega^{-k|M|}\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{\ell=1}^p\omega^{\ell\sum M}\right).
\end{eqnarray*}
The last algebraic step is to evaluate the inner sums, each of which is a finite geometric series. There are two types. If $n$ is an integer with $n=0\bmod p$, then $\sum_{k=1}^p\omega^{kn}$ degenerates to a sum of $p$. However, if $n\ne0\bmod p$, then $\sum_{k=1}^p\omega^{kn}=(1-\omega^{np})/(1-\omega^n)$, which is outright $0$. Putting all this together, we have
$$S=p^2\cdot|\{M\subseteq\{1,\ldots,2p\}: \textstyle{\sum} M=0\bmod p \quad\text{and}\quad  |M|=0\bmod p\}|.$$
There are two boundary cases: $M=\varnothing$ and $M=\{1,\ldots,2p\}$, and in both of these cases $ \sum M=0\bmod p$. Otherwise,  we've reduced the evaluation of this sum to the combinatorial problem of enumerating the subsets of $\{1,\ldots,2p\}$ with $p$ elements which have a sum divisible by $p$. There are $\binom{2p}p$ subsets of $\{1,\ldots,2p\}$ with $p$ elements. A consequence of  Wilson's theorem is that $\binom{2p}p=2\bmod p$, and there are two exceptional such subsets here, namely the lower members$\{1,2,3,\ldots,p\}$ and the upper members $\{p+1,p+2,\ldots,2p\}$. In both of these cases $p$ divides the sum of the members of the sets. The remaining $\binom{2p}p-2$ sets have sums that are uniformly distributed among the $p$ remainders $0,1,\dots,p-1\bmod p$. As a result,
$$S=p^2\Big(\underbrace{2}_{\text{boundary cases}}+\underbrace{2}_{\text{lower and upper}}+\underbrace{\frac1p(\binom{2p}p-2)}_{\text{sum}=0\bmod p}\Big),$$
which is equivalent to your claim.

Comment: Well done. I tried as well using a different approach and kept getting $S=p(\binom{2p}{p} + 4p - 4)$, just like @Anton instead of getting to $S=p(\binom{2p}{p} + 4p - 2)$

Comment: Nice one! I got the idea but I cannot understand one of the last parts: "The remaining $\binom{2p}{p}-2$ sets have sums that are uniformly distributed among the $p$ remainders". Can you please explain it a little bit more?

Comment: You can partition the subsets of $\{1,\ldots,2p\}$ with $p$ members (except for two sets) into equivalence classes so that each equivalence class contains exactly $p$ sets with the remainders $0, 1, \ldots, p-1\bmod p$. One way to do this for a set $M\subseteq\{1,\ldots,2p\}$ would be to shift the lower members $m\in\{1,\ldots,p\}$ by $1\bmod p$, but leave the upper half  $m\in\{p+1,\ldots,2p\}$ alone. The iterates of this "half shift" would form the needed equivalence classes.

Comment: @RusMay Thx, I got it!

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [@RusMay](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/17853/rus-may)'s answer, I found a mistake in my own calculations. I forgot about trivial corner cases that should be treated carefully. It was here:

> But I think (but have not proven that yet) that $\sum\limits_{t \in E} t^i = 0$ for every $i \neq p$.

Actually, it is true for every $i$ that is not divisible by $p$. So, I have not taken into an account two cases: $i = 0$ and $i = 2p$. And now we have:

$$S'' = p \binom{2p}{p} + p \binom{2p}{0} + p \binom{2p}{2p} = p \binom{2p}{p} + 2p $$

And the answer is:

$$S = S' + S'' = 4 p (p - 1) + p \binom{2p}{p} + 2p = p(\binom{2p}{p} + 4p - 2)$$

Yep, the right answer!